# Different threads using same instance of DbContext, called from within DelegatingHandler

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have .Net Core 3.1 application that is using EF Core 3.1.9.  During a specific process I am getting the following error:

**A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913**

I am using Dependency Injection for the DbContext and have gone through all the flows to make sure everything is properly and immediately `await`'ed.

The error occurs within **LtiUserRepository.cs** which will be shown below.

That process starts with an external http call using an HttpClient that has a custom MessageHandler, registered in **Startup.cs**:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<MyRepository>("MyCustomUserClient", client =>
  {
    var canvasUrl = Configuration.GetSection("Urls:Removed").Value ?? "https://example.com/";
    client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(removed);
  }).AddHttpMessageHandler<LtiUserApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler>();
```

The code that initiates the HTTP Call is:

```cs
public async Task<PlatformQuizSubmissions> GetUserQuiz(string courseId, string quizId)
  {
    var path = $"api/v1/courses/{courseId}/quizzes/{quizId}/submission";
    var response = await _myCustomUserClient.GetAsync(path);
    // some stuff
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Some other stuff
  }
```

The purpose of the custom MessageHandler is to check for a header, get some data, and append a query parameter to each request

```cs
public sealed class LtiUserApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly ILtiUserService _userService;

    public LtiUserApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, ILtiUserService ltiUserService)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
        _userService = ltiUserService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var obo = _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["QT-OBO"];
        // THIS IS THE PART THAT QUERIES THE DATABASE
        var user = await _userService.Get(new Guid(obo));
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uriBuilder.Query))
        {
          uriBuilder.Query = $"as_user_id={user.PlatformUserId}";
        }
        else
        {
          uriBuilder.Query = $"{uriBuilder.Query}&as_user_id={user.PlatformUserId}";
        }
        request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
        
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You can see above that the MessageHandler calls `_userservice.Get`, which is this:

```cs
public async Task<LtiUser> Get(Guid guid)
{
  return await _ltiUserRepository.Get(guid);
}
```

That simply returns from the repository, which is this:

```cs
public class LtiUserRepository : ILtiUserRepository
{
  private readonly SqlDbContext _db;
  private readonly IMapper _mapper;
  private readonly ILogger<LtiUserRepository> _logger;
  
  public LtiUserRepository(SqlDbContext sqlDbContext, IMapper mapper, ILoggerFactory logger)
  {
    _db = sqlDbContext;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _logger = logger != null ? logger.CreateLogger<LtiUserRepository>() : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
  }
  public async Task<LtiUser> Get(Guid guid)
  {
    try
    {
      return await _db.LtiUsers
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(l => l.UUID == guid)
        .ProjectTo<LtiUser>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // This is where the error is caught.
      _logger.LogCritical($"Could not get LtiUser via (UUID) {guid} : {ex.Message}");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The database is registered in **Startup.cs** with:

```cs
protected virtual void ConfigureDatabaseServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<SqlDbContext>(
                o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString")),
                ServiceLifetime.Transient);
}
```

When I hit this endpoint using ApacheBench with 20 requests, concurrency of 2 I get this error anywhere from 2 to 10 times.  However, looking at the following snippet  from the MessageHandler (**LtiUserApiAuthenticationHttpClientHandler**) again:

```cs
var user = await _userService.Get(new Guid(obo));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uriBuilder.Query))
{
  uriBuilder.Query = $"as_user_id={user.PlatformUserId}";
}
else
{
  uriBuilder.Query = $"{uriBuilder.Query}&as_user_id={user.PlatformUserId}";
}
```

If I replace `user.PlatformUserId` with a hardcoded, known value, (and comment out the call to `_userService.Get`) I can use AB with 1000 requests and a concurrency of 20 and have 0 occurrences of the issue.  That leads me to believe I have it narrowed down to the offending flow, but am not sure of the correct way to do this.

Comment: Don't do that. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and multi-entity Repository, not a database connection or model. And HttpClient handlers are meant to work on the messages, not execute business code or access databases

Comment: Beyond these problems, there's a security problem as well. Handlers are cached per factory, not per user or request. Which HttpContext is that client handler going to call? If you have 1000 requests from different users, which headers is this going to read? This isn't an HttpClient bug.

Comment: Using `ServiceLifetime.Transient` in AddDbContext won't fix anything. It means your code will create a lot of DbContext instances but never dispose them. The actual lifetime of the DbContext will depend on the lifetime of `ILtiUserService`. If that's a singleton, then the same DbContext instance will be used for every call to that service

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm refactoring so that the work is not done in the MessageHandler